# Angular 6 - Get all changed values on FormGroup

Tags: angular

I'm new with Angular and I'm wondering if we can get all the values that has changed and only those one.

For example,

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: '',
  age: '',
  city: ''
});
```

In my html template, I would like to have 3 inputs, one for each formcontrol of my form. I also want to have a button, when I click on it, the resulting action should be sending to my backend only the changed values (PATCH method).

I don't see how we can do this. I've tried with the observable 'valueChanges', but it returns the whole form and I don't see how it can help me.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Take a snapshot of the form when you populate it first. Compare with that snapshot before submitting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's a workaround that I've been using for sometime and it's working.

Suppose you have `form` of type `FormBuilder` and the initial values of each part of the form are stored in `info` obj. For example, our form has only a username and an email.

in `ngOnInit`, we subscribe to any changes:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(dt => this.fieldChanges());
```

then we implement the method:

```
fieldChanges() {
    this.anyChanges = false;
    let username = this.form.controls['username'] && this.form.controls['username'].value || '';
    let email = this.form.controls['email'] && this.form.controls['email'].value || '';

    if (this.info['username'] !== username.trim() || this.info['email'] !== email.trim()) {
        this.anyChanges = true;
    }
}
```

From this code, if there exists any changes, the `anyChange` property will be set to `true`. If you separate the conditions, you can access all the changes for individual form control elements. But if you only care about whether there was any changes, you can use a shorter version of the code above, using `Object.keys(info).forEach(...)` and then you will be able to detect changes in a more generalized and better way. Or if you wish to store the fields that've been changed, you can define an object and in the `forEach` part, you add the keys and values of the changed fields to this object. At the end, you have an object of changed fields with their old/new values, as needed.

Comment: Hey, very nice explanation. Please also post your answer to this link which contains the same question in a different way :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449101/get-the-change-object-from-form-group-in-angular-12

Comment: Thanks. But the link is broken

Comment: Okay yes the question removed by author , right!! sorry for the trouble